# sudo apt-get/update manager error

Tags: updates

I ran a terminal command and ever since I've been having problems.

The terminal command I entered was

```
echo off "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs)/partner Packages" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I honestly can't even remember why I was doing this again but it was something I found off a forum. Ever since I entered the command, `sudo apt-get update` doesn't work, and update manager has an error. Stating the following..

An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

```
'E:Type 'off' is not known on line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list, E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm..your sources.list file seems to be modified by the command you used and cant be accessed now.
The sources.list file contains the list of repositories from which apt-get gets its software.

So to correct this use

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

which would bring up the text file sources.list for editing

Only remove the line that you added, which will look like,

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ubuntu13.04
```

and dont touch anything else.
then save the file and try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Tell us how it goes.

Comment: when i try the gksudo command you suggest i get the following error. (gksudo:5539): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: ok..then try    sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list    instead of gksudo

Comment: sudo: gedit: command not found - i have no clue why its doing this.

Comment: this could be because some text editor (other than gedit) is installed on your system.

Comment: find out which text editor is installed and then type

Comment: sudo <name of text editor> /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: my text editor is called "scratch" - trying sudo scratch /etc/apt/sources.list brought up "command not found" again.

Comment: can you open your file manager as root? try sudo nautillus or sudo nautilus

Comment: and the text editor perhaps is Scratch and not scratch so also try sudo Scratch /etc/apt/sources.list (case sensitive)

Comment: again command not found. sorry to be such a burden, i think i might have to reinstall.

Comment: i dont think you need to reinstall for such a small thing, you could try right clicking inside your file manager and see if there is an option like 'open as root'

Comment: no option to open as root, show hidden files seems to be a rather similar option. everything else is just create folder, etc etc.

Comment: you could also try the 'vi' text editor thats standard on all unix/linux systems but its a bit complex. try sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list , enter your password, then the file sources.list would be brought up, click on Esc key on your keyboard, navigate to the line to be deleted, and delete it , then type in a  : (colon) , then after colon type wq (to save and quit) , it would look like :wq  then press enter and thats it.

Comment: restart your system and then try again sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 0):

First Open /etc/apt/sources.list and delete that line
After that run folliwing commands

For Open File Use Following Commands

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

After delete that line save the file and run follwing commands

```
apt-get clean all
apt-get update
```

Comment: entering your sudo vim command brings up "sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list"

if it makes any difference, im running Luna (the latest version of elementaryOS) but i figured this would be the best place to ask considering eOS is based off of Ubuntu.

Comment: try sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'vi' text editor that is standard on all unix/linux systems but its a bit complex.

type `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` , enter your password, then the file sources.list would be brought up,

click on Esc key on your keyboard, navigate to the line to be deleted, and delete it using the delete key,

then type in a : (colon) , then after colon type wq (to save and quit) , it would look like :wq then press enter and thats it.

**help-**
by pressing the Escape key in vi it brings up the navigation mode.

by pressing the : key it brings up the command mode, and the command is wq
(it will look like `:wq`   as a whole)

Comment: sort of lost for words on how to do this but this is whats brought up after entering your command. --- E325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name "/etc/apt/.sources.list.swp" owned by: root dated: Tue Aug 13 02:02:28 2013 file name: /etc/apt/sources.list modified: YES user name: root host name: rotart-System-Product-Name process ID: 19185 While opening file "/etc/apt/sources.list" dated: Tue Aug 13 00:42:34 2013 ----- then im not quite sure how to edit the file itself.

Comment: restart your system and try again sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: you could navigate to the directory (using file manager) to /etc/apt/  and check if theres a file like sources.list.bak (backup file for sources.list) or any file like sources.list~ perhaps these files would be in their original state and would not contain the line that you added... in that case reomve your sources.list file by sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list ... and rename the backup file as sources.list .. sudo rename /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list   ..and then try  sudo apt-get update......finally if all else fails just reinstall :(  and be careful in the future